# Why is Gitlab pipeline failing with 403 request when using Environment?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a weird issue, my pipelines basically build K8s manifest file to deploy a specific microservice on K8s cluster. I use shell code to do Kubectl apply in the deploy stage. also the Kubeconfig I use has all the permissions needed. what is happening is when I introduce Environments https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/, I get deployment failed and in the pipeline I get 403 forbidden request. the only difference I can see is in the curl calls Kubectl is doing there is an extra header that has Authorization Bearer.
Anyone faced a problem like this or have any Idea what could be the problem?

"reason": "Forbidden",
"details": {
"name": "abcd-service-hc",
"kind": "services"
},
"code": 403
}]

I tried verbose the Kubectl to check any difference and as I mentioned the only thing I found is the extra header , also I checked that the Kubeconfig is the same and it has the required permissions

Comment: Can you add the related parts in .gitlab-ci.yml? mask the sensitive data

Comment: @SuleymanSah thanks for the reply , the deployment script is straight forward :

    - kubectl apply -f ${K8S_ARTIFACTS_PATH}

what I just found is that when I put the environment it creates a new random namespace and new random serviceAccount and looks like it tries to execute everything on using that service account which is weird because it is the exact same thing Im using (just added the environment)